# Change backcolor according to color selected from combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, background-color

In my form I have a combobox. It has color names like Red, Yellow, etc.

I want to change backcolor for my form to match the color selected from combobox when I click a button. So far I have this:

```
private void button_Pass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox_color.SelectedText == "Red")
    {
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
    else if (comboBox_color.SelectedText == "Yellow")
    {
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    }
    else
    {
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    }
}
```

When I click the button, the form's BackColor is always set to Blue. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: So what problem do you have with this code?

Comment: Andy it's not showing exact color.. it's showing only blue color :-/

Comment: Well, have you tried to debug it? Probably your conditions concerning `comboBox_color.SelectedText` is not being met.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the opening `{` and find out what `comboBox_color.SelectedText` is at that point.

Comment: Sayse I did not understand!

Comment: @Sayse - that might be an improvement or it might be irrelevant. It's not an answer to this question.

Comment: during debugging does control go into the ''if' and ''else if'' block. and does the selectedtext show red and yellow as values.

Comment: Try to replace 'this' with the combobox id

Comment: `SelectedText` is __not__ what you __think__ it is! (Hint: use `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()` instead!)

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I misthought that `System.Drawing.Color` was also an enum in which case I was pointing out that this question is pretty much a duplicate.

Comment: Brought the actual question from the comments into the question body.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Color.FromName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
this.BackColor = Color.FromName(comboBox_color.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

> If the name parameter is not the valid name of a predefined color, the FromName method creates a Color structure that has an ARGB value of 0 (that is, all ARGB components are 0).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the property of the ComboBox you are comparing to.

The SelectedText property is used to get or set the text that is selected in the editable portion of a ComboBox.

The SelectedItem property is used to get or set the selected item in the ComboBox. If you wanted to get the Text displayed for that selected item you could do that like this:

```
comboBox_color.SelectedItem.ToString();
```